# CodeIgniter cache - system or application

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

Confused.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

says caches are created in `application/cache`.

But, in the system `config.php` it says the default cache is in `system/cache/`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/cache/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
```

Which, if any, does CI use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application/cache` is correct. It was changed to `application/cache` from `system/cache` in 2.0.0 according to the [change log](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html). The comments just weren't updated.